# Inserting integer into array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, integer

I'm not really on point with Swift yet and there is a problem that is starting to be a tad annoying.

I just want to add integer in a double dimensional array but it is always returning the same error code : "fatal error : Array index out of range"

```
var arrayVolley = [[Int]]()

init(){
    self.arrayVolley = [[]]
}
```

Here is where I try to insert :

```
func addPoints(score : Int, x : Int, y : Int){

    if (score > 11 || score < 0){ //11 will be translated as 10x
        println("Error on score value")
    }
    else {
        if (x>6 || y>6){
            println("Out of array")
        }
        else{
            arrayVolley[x][y]=score
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main :

```
var i=0
var j=0
for i in 0...6 {
    for j in 0...6{
        println("Entrez le score")
        var scoreinput=input()
        var score = scoreinput.toInt()
        distance.addPoints(score!, x: i, y: j)
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Comment: Why do you have `var i = 0` and `var j = 0`? I think you can remove those. Also, I think in your `init()` function it is redundant to set `self.arrayVolley = [[]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use append to add the integer to the array it is automatically the next idex. It think if the index was never used it gives an error e.g.

```
var test = [Int]()
test.append(2) // array is empty so 0 is added as index
test.append(4)
test.append(5) // 2 is added as max index array is not [2,4,5]
test[0] = 3 // works because the index 0 exist cause the where more then 1 element in array -> [3,4,5]
test[4] = 5 // does not work cause index for never added with append
```

or you intialize the array in the correct size, but it's need a size:

```
var test = [Int](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0) // [0,0,0,0,0]
test[0] = 3 //[3,0,0,0,0]
test[4] = 5 [3,0,0,0,5]
```

It hope this helps you if not please feel free to comment.