# "Array index out of range" when choosing photos in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I cant figure out what's the problem here.

I have 6 images and when i click on them it popsup a image picker. If i choose a photo with a sequence, like 1,2,3,4,5,6... it works. But when i choose the first photo that's not the first one (array[0]), i get an error:

> `$"Array index out of range"

Here is my code:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var imagemEscolhida = -1

@IBOutlet var firstImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var secondImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var thirdImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var fourthImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var fifthImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var sixthImageView: UIImageView!


@IBAction func firstImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    imagemEscolhida = 1
    abreBibliotecaFotos(imagemEscolhida)

}

@IBAction func secondImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagemEscolhida = 2
    abreBibliotecaFotos(imagemEscolhida)

}

@IBAction func thirdImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagemEscolhida = 3
    abreBibliotecaFotos(imagemEscolhida)
}

@IBAction func fourthImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagemEscolhida = 4
    abreBibliotecaFotos(imagemEscolhida)
}

@IBAction func fifthImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagemEscolhida = 5
    abreBibliotecaFotos(imagemEscolhida)
}

@IBAction func sixthImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagemEscolhida = 6
    abreBibliotecaFotos(imagemEscolhida)
}

func abreBibliotecaFotos (img: Int )
{
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        firstImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        restaurante.imagem.insert(pickedImage, atIndex: imagemEscolhida-1)

        switch imagemEscolhida
        {
        case 1:
            firstImageView.image = restaurante.imagem[0]
        case 2:
            secondImageView.image = restaurante.imagem[1]
        case 3:
            thirdImageView.image = restaurante.imagem[2]
        case 4:
            fourthImageView.image = restaurante.imagem[3]
        case 5:
            fifthImageView.image = restaurante.imagem[4]
        case 6:
            sixthImageView.image = restaurante.imagem[5]
        default:
            println("Something else")
        }



        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
}


}
```

Comment: On what line code crashes?

Comment: where you defined the array ?

Comment: I have this:
`static var imagem: [UIImage] = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize the array before you use it in the correct size. I would like to refer to my answer to a really similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797127/inserting-integer-into-array-in-swift/31797255#31797255).
So initialize it from 0 to 5 at definition then your code should work.

Comment: How do i initialize an array of images like this:
`static var imagem: [UIImage] = []`

Comment: I would try `static var imagem  = [UIImage](count: 5, repeatedValue: nil)`

Comment: I tried that and gives me ` Unexpected trailing closure`

Comment: Otherwise try this `var imagem = [UIImage](count: 5, repeatedValue: UIImage())` both of them worked for me in a playground where i tested them.

Comment: Yea.. but if i add it to my project gives the same error =/

Comment: I added STATIC to the last code you sent and it works now :) THANK YOU!!

Solved: `static var imagem = [UIImage](count: 5, repeatedValue: UIImage())`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `restaurante.imagem` array is empty and your code crashes because you try to insert something at index which is higher than the maximum index of the array - which is `0`.

The line to blame is:

```
restaurante.imagem.insert(pickedImage, atIndex: imagemEscolhida-1)
```

Comment: Thats right, should create an array with 5 positions?
My array now is:
`static var imagem: [UIImage] = []`

Comment: I would rather use `append` instead of `insert` and then check the array size later. But I don't know your requirements.

Comment: In this case I must use insert =/

How do I initialize an array like this?

Comment: You have to add six dummy objects to the array. Like following:         `let img = UIImage()
        var array : [UIImage] = [img, img, img, img, img, img]`
But still, this looks like a bad design to me.